# Static Addresses On DHCP Range

Tags: dhcp, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I have DHCP server setup on my network. I have set of computers that need to remain on and based on their work if the upstream network goes out it needs to remain on with the correct addresses. In the DHCP servers these computers have DHCP reservations so they get the same addresses. To ensure if the DHCP servers are unavailable we set the addresses on the computers as Static addresses to the same address as the reservation. That way if they accidentally get reset or network settings get reset they will get the right address.

After setting the address statically when connected to the network the computer shows the network as an Unidentified Network. If I turn it back to DHCP it shows the network as the correct DOMAIN. Why as static will it not show the network as the Domain?

Comment: Please give more details around this statement : "computer shows the network as an Unidentified Network". Please provide a cmd line or screenshot showing the problem. Also, what problems does this cause? Are you also setting the DNS servers the same as DHCP would set them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the default domain in the DNS settings? Remember that the machine's default domain is sent in the DHCP packet, along with the DNS servers to use. Make sure that everything that comes in DHCP is set in the static case, especially including the DNS server IPs.

For Windows, the place you go for the default domain is the DNS tab in the network connection's Properties | Advanced window. Instead of Default domain, Windows has decided to call it "DNS suffix for this connection"; fill that in; you may also have to check "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration"

Comment: I have set the IP address and DNS servers the same as if it were coming from DHCP. Still showing as an unidentified network.

Comment: Question remains: have you set the default domain in DNS?

Comment: I checked all the options in the DNS tab. Can't find a default domain section. Can you direct me in the right place?

Comment: Certainly. The DNS tab is the right place. Instead of Default domain, Windows has decided to call it "DNS suffix for this connection"; fill that in; you may also have to check "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration".

Comment: please update our answer to include the info above.